# How to get a window handle for error output in .NET Core 6 compared to .NET Framework in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, pinvoke

For context :

I am in charge of upgrading a service from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET Core 6. This service is called by a master service that start some others services. This master service is the error handle output of all these child services, my service being no exception. To get the handle of this output window to write to the log from my service, `Win32::GetStdHandle` is used.

This works flawlessly in .NET Framework: When starting up the application in Visual Studio 2022 to debug, all logging informations goes to the `Output` window, and when started with the master service, it is logged to the master service console window.

Here is the issue : In .NET Core 6, under the exact same conditions, the `Win32::GetStdHandle` call returns 0, an invalid handle.

**How can I get the GetStdHandle call to work as expected, returning the correct handle in .NET Core 6, or any workaround to get the STD_ERROR_HANDLE of the process that started the service?**

Reproducible example, in either .NET Framework 4.7.2 or .NET Core 6 :

(Note: will output to console in a console application, and will output to the `Output` if in a Windows Application and started in Visual Studio.)

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SafeFileHandle handle;
        TestLogHandle test = new TestLogHandle();
        test.Init();
        test.SendMessage("aaaaaaa");
    }
}

class TestLogHandle
{
    private SafeFileHandle _handle;
    private FileStream _stream;
    const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    internal FileStream Init()
    {
        IntPtr iStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
        _handle = new SafeFileHandle(iStdOut, true); //returns 0 in .NET Core 6

        if (_handle.IsInvalid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid handle."); //throws in .NET Core 6
        }
        _stream = new FileStream(_handle, FileAccess.Write, BUFFER_SIZE, false);
        return _stream;
    }

    internal void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        if (_stream == null) return;
        var encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] messageBuffer = encoder.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}\r\n", message));
        _stream.Write(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
        _stream.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't reproduce. Works fine with .NET 6, 7, x86, x64, in cmd, terminal, Visual Studio, etc. You should provide a fully compilable project (post on github, internet, whatever).

Comment: @SimonMourier My apologies, you're perfectly correct in the case of a Console Application, but not in a Windows Application when using Visual Studio (The STD_ERROR_HANDLE is no longer the "Output" window). I should have clarified that I'm investigating as to why this behavior is different when using .NET Core in Visual Studio.

Comment: GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE) => 0 just mean there's nothing defined you can write to, it's not incorrect nor unexpected. You can just call AllocConsole (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) so you have a console to output to, for example.

Comment: @SimonMourier Coincidentally just what I was looking for :). Thanks, I guess Visual Studio does not assign the Output window as STD_ERROR_HANDLE in .NET Core compared to .NET Framework.